# Delay in alerts being sent out

Tags: 2010

We have a list that has immediate alerts configured for approximately 12,000 users. Our immediate timer job is set to run every 2 minutes. The alerts are taking a long time to send out and I wanted to know what we can do to improve this. For example, one user received the alert message 12 minutes after the list item was created. Still another user received the alerts over 40 minutes after the item was created. Is there anything we can do to improve the send time? We are running SP 2010.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint really has never done well at bulk email operations.  Since you are describing a rather specialized case, what you might want to do is offload the 'spamming' to the mail server which is better designed for it.  By that, I mean have your admins create a dummy user in AD with a mailbox in Exchange and also create a separate email distribution list containing the 12,000 people.  Configure SharePoint to alert just that one dummy account and then configure the dummy account to autoforward its emails to the distribution list.

You could get fancy and create server rules on the dummy account that would let it forward to different distribution lists based on some criteria in the alert itself, allowing it to be used for multiple lists and multiple bulk distributions.

Comment: That sounds like a viable idea but one of the requirements of the alerts on this list is that users should be able to opt out (we opt them all in at the beginning of the year). It seems like the distribution list idea would break this logic.

Comment: Very true.  Opting Out would have to either be a manual process done by an admin or a quick web page could be created that would handle the opt-out automatically